# FTP download background worker

Tags: c#, ftp

I have this code to download from ftp and  would like to put it into a backgroundworker.

```
void BtnDownloadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog fldDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (fldDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            Download(fldDlg.SelectedPath, lstFiles.SelectedItem.ToString());    
}

private void Download(string filePath, string fileName)
        {
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
            try
            {
                FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(filePath + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);

                reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + PathFolders + "/" + fileName));
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
                Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                long cl = response.ContentLength;
                int bufferSize = 2048;
                int readCount;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (readCount > 0)
                {
                    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                    readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                ftpStream.Close();
                outputStream.Close();
                response.Close();
            }       
}
```

Can you help me? I am new to C#...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to your [free-of-charge, 24/7 coding service](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to use:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Download(fldDlg.SelectedPath, lstFiles.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

This will use an Asychronous task to complete your download.  Since your UI is not reliant on any of the code inside the download this will work fine. If your Download process needed to integrate back into your UI upon completion then you would be better off using the BackgroundWorker. In this case, however, i think you are fine using a Task.